# Android HTML5 submit form in browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I wanted to know how do I submit a form into the phone's browser, because it opens the link into the same app. I've installed the cordova inappbrowser and tried the sample code below, no luck.

```
<form action="http://www.random.link" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="submit" id="sb" value="Submit"></form>
```

I did some searching and only found how to open links in the phone's browser, and I wanna do it on submitting form instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say that in android app you want to submit form, you need to use webview as follows 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Make sure the form that you create in html should have method get
Load your html using following 
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/index.html", htmlfilecontent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already did that, app is perfectly running, it's just weird that whenever I submit forms, It opens on the same webview as the app, which isn't the behavior I wanted.

Comment: what do you mean ? you mean when you click submit in webivew form it should launch and submit in new browser ?

Comment: No, it can open a link on new browser on click on submit on webview, however the result has to be returned in same request where you have submitted.

Comment: as a solution once you get the response, you can render the response on external browser, utililze " public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) " event. use following code. Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url;
startActivity(browserIntent);